# Google app-engine for application that doesn't use app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, grails

As an experiment I attempted do deploy my "regular" (=vanilla create-application) grails-app to google app-engine.

Even though I have removed my repo locally, re-cloned to different folders etc I still get this message when I do a clean, or run-app or anything for that matter.

```
No Google AppEngine SDK specified. Either set APPENGINE_HOME in your environment or specify google.appengine.sdk in your grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I may have spoken too soon, I changed my app.name in application.properties and that solved it, I can't verify it but I guessing ivy-related (just a guess)

Answer (score 0):

I may have spoken too soon, I changed my app.name in application.properties and that solved it, I can't verify it but I guessing ivy-related (just a guess)